# Run a code and insert to db only once when server starts nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a permission service with a method create permission.

```
export class PermissionService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Permission)
        private readonly permissionRepository: Repository<Permission>
    ) { }

    async createPermission(perArr: CreatePermissionDTO[]) {
        for (let i = 0; i < perArr.length; i++) {
            console.log(perArr[i]);
            const permission = await this.permissionRepository.findOne({ pcode: perArr[i].pcode });
            if (!permission) {
                let permissionObject = {
                    pcode: perArr[i].pcode,
                    permissionName: perArr[i].permissionName
                }
                await this.permissionRepository.insert(permissionObject)
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

My another file is permission constant file

```
export let permissionListArry = [
    {
        pcode : 'P-CREATE-USER',
        permissionName : 'User with this permission can create User'
    }
]
```

I want to run create permission method only once when the nest js server starts . I tried OnModuleInit on my app.module.ts file but does not seems to work.

Comment: The problem is I have not create any module for this file so whenever I run it from app module it throws an error that cannot resolve the dependencies of AppModule

Comment: You can implement the `OnModuleInit` hook directly in your `PermissionService`. If this doesn't help, please post the code that is not working for you and the error message you receive.